# Add header and footer to a page using reportLab

Tags: python, pdf, header, footer, reportlab

I am trying to include both header and footer on a single page. I referred [A multiline(paragraph) footer and header in reportlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827871/a-multilineparagraph-footer-and-header-in-reportlab) and used the method stated by Jochen and NateB80. But only the header gets generated not the footer.

```
def header(canvas, doc, content):
    canvas.saveState()
    w, h = content.wrap(doc.width, doc.topMargin)
    content.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin, doc.height + doc.topMargin - h)
    canvas.restoreState()


def footer(canvas, doc, content):
    canvas.saveState()
    w, h = content.wrap(doc.width, doc.bottomMargin)
    content.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin, h)
    canvas.restoreState()

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

PAGESIZE = pagesizes.portrait(pagesizes.A4)
# PAGESIZE = letter
pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(filename, pagesize=PAGESIZE, leftMargin=2.2*cm, rightMargin=2.2*cm,
        topMargin=1.5*cm,bottomMargin=2.5*cm)
frameh = Frame(pdf.leftMargin, pdf.bottomMargin, pdf.width, pdf.height - 2 * cm, id='normal')
header_content = Paragraph("This is a header. testing testing testing  ", styles['Normal'])
templateh = PageTemplate(id='test', frames=frameh, onPage=partial(header, content=header_content))
pdf.addPageTemplates([templateh])

framef = Frame(pdf.leftMargin, pdf.bottomMargin, pdf.width, pdf.height, id='normal')
footer_content = Paragraph("This is  footer.  It goes on every page.  ", styles['Normal'])
templatef = PageTemplate(id='test', frames=framef, onPage=partial(footer, content=footer_content))
pdf.addPageTemplates([templatef])
```

I also tried the below, but still, no footer is getting generated.

```
 pdf.addPageTemplates([
                      PageTemplate(id='footer', frames=[frameh, framef], onPage=partial(header, content=header_content)),
                      ])
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to combine `header` and `footer` into one function and put it in one `PageTemplate`

```py
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, PageTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.frames import Frame
from reportlab.lib import pagesizes
from reportlab.platypus.paragraph import Paragraph
from functools import partial

def header(canvas, doc, content):
    canvas.saveState()
    w, h = content.wrap(doc.width, doc.topMargin)
    content.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin, doc.height + doc.bottomMargin + doc.topMargin - h)
    canvas.restoreState()

def footer(canvas, doc, content):
    canvas.saveState()
    w, h = content.wrap(doc.width, doc.bottomMargin)
    content.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin, h)
    canvas.restoreState()

def header_and_footer(canvas, doc, header_content, footer_content):
    header(canvas, doc, header_content)
    footer(canvas, doc, footer_content)

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

filename = "out.pdf"

PAGESIZE = pagesizes.portrait(pagesizes.A4)

pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(filename, pagesize=PAGESIZE, 
        leftMargin = 2.2 * cm, 
        rightMargin = 2.2 * cm,
        topMargin = 1.5 * cm, 
        bottomMargin = 2.5 * cm)

frame = Frame(pdf.leftMargin, pdf.bottomMargin, pdf.width, pdf.height, id='normal')

header_content = Paragraph("This is a header. testing testing testing  ", styles['Normal'])
footer_content = Paragraph("This is a footer. It goes on every page.  ", styles['Normal'])

template = PageTemplate(id='test', frames=frame, onPage=partial(header_and_footer, header_content=header_content, footer_content=footer_content))

pdf.addPageTemplates([template])

pdf.build([Paragraph("This is content")])
```